# how to extract the class property name of divs in python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to use python beautifulsoup to extract the class property name in a piece of html content. For example, `<td><div class="na"></div></td>`, "na" is the string I want to get, as sometimes the html content will switch to `<td><div class="fail"></div></td>`
I want to catch the property changes from "na" to "fail" or from "fail" to "na", and report it.

Any ideas?

Comment: A BS element has a dictionary interface. Once you find a `<div>`, just use a dictionary lookup: `soup.findAll('div')[0]['class']`.

Comment: @DYZ, great thanks. It works. I did not catch this point in the document of  beautifulsoup. does that mean soup.findAll('div')[0] is a dictionary type or has a function to override hash operation?

Comment: soup.find('div')[0] is a navigable string object.